# MacOSX:VLC player is not compatible with QtWebEngine

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, libvlc, qtwebengine

I have a Python script embedded with VLC player and QtWebEngine that plays both video and web pages.

It works well on Windows. When I moved it to run on MacOSX, the QtWebEngine page was blocked by a black rectangle, and the VLC player became invisible.

When the VLC player and QtWebEngine are separated into separate programs, they work normally.

Here's my script code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import os
import vlc

from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtWebEngineWidgets import *

class test_widget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(test_widget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.__ui__()

    def __ui__(self):
        t_lay_parent = QVBoxLayout()
        t_lay_content = QHBoxLayout()
        t_lay_tool = QHBoxLayout()

        self.label_media = QLabel()
        self.webengine = QWebEngineView()
        t_lay_content.addWidget(self.label_media, 1)
        t_lay_content.addWidget(self.webengine, 1)

        self.lineedit_url = QLineEdit("http://baidu.com")
        self.button_go = QPushButton("Go")
        self.button_play = QPushButton("Play")
        t_lay_tool.addWidget(self.lineedit_url)
        t_lay_tool.addWidget(self.button_go)
        t_lay_tool.addWidget(self.button_play)

        self.button_go.clicked.connect(self.slt_go)
        self.button_play.clicked.connect(self.slt_play)

        t_lay_parent.addLayout(t_lay_content)
        t_lay_parent.addLayout(t_lay_tool)
        self.setLayout(t_lay_parent)

        self.instance = vlc.Instance("-q")
        self.m_player = self.instance.media_player_new()
        t_wid = self.label_media.winId()
        if sys.platform.startswith('linux'):  # linux
            self.m_player.set_xwindow(t_wid)
        elif sys.platform == "win32":  # windows
            self.m_player.set_hwnd(t_wid)
        elif sys.platform == "darwin":  # mac
            self.m_player.set_nsobject(t_wid)

    def slt_go(self):
        t_url = self.lineedit_url.text()
        self.webengine.setUrl(QUrl(t_url))

    def slt_play(self):
        t_media = self.instance.media_new("1.mp4")
        self.m_player.set_media(t_media)
        self.m_player.play()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = test_widget()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here's my working environment

MacOSX: 10.10.5

Python: 2.7.5

PyQt: 5.9.0

VLC: 2.2.8

Comment: Does it work separately?

Comment: Yes, they work separately. But when I play video first and then browse the page, video will become invisible